# Scrolling Left To Right With Actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, if-statement, scroll

maybe someone can help me with this Adobe Flash Actionscript 3.0 question.

I'm trying to make a timeline with "buttons" on the left and right most part of the screen so the timeline can be scrubbed when the mouse goes to those parts of the screen. The buttons themselves are simply there as a means to show the user where they need to hover over in order to make the timeline scroll in that direction.

I've been able to get the timeline to scrub once with the code below, but I want to make it so that it keeps scrolling for the duration of time that the user keeps their mouse over it.

Also I placed an If statement that prevents the timeline from being scrolled off the screen.

Currently the code is only used once and goes left to right on the X axis by 15. How do I make it so it keeps steadily moving to the left or right until the mouse is off the scroll buttons?

```
    //Scroll Logic
backScroll_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, backScroll);

function backScroll(e:MouseEvent){
    if(timeLine.x < 1406.55){
        timeLine.x = timeLine.x + 15;}
}

forwardScroll_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, forwardScroll);

function forwardScroll(e:MouseEvent){
    if(timeLine.x > 0){
        timeLine.x = timeLine.x - 15};
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want a continuous scroll, use an enter frame event listener to trigger the scroll. The buttons will then have two listeners triggering the scrolling on/off for either side.

```
var scrollingBack:Boolean;
var scrollingForward:Boolean;
backScroll_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, backScrollOn);
backScroll_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, backScrollOff);
function backScrollOn(e:MouseEvent):void { scrollingBack=true; }
function backScrollOff(e:MouseEvent):void { scrollingBack=false; }
forwardScroll_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, forwardScrollOn);
forwardScroll_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, forwardScrollOff);
function forwardScrollOn(e:MouseEvent):void { scrollingForward=true; }
function forwardScrollOff(e:MouseEvent):void { scrollingForward=false; }
timeline.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,doScroll);

function doScroll(e:Event):void {
    if (scrollingForward) {
         if(timeLine.x > 0){
            timeLine.x = timeLine.x - 15};
    } else if (scrollingBack) {
        if(timeLine.x < 1406.55){
            timeLine.x = timeLine.x + 15;}
    }
}
```

Comment: All of this code makes sense to me except for one part.
The "scrollingBack" and "scrollingForward" are coming up as undefined.
I know that if it's an object, I simply have to tell Flash to listen for that specific object's instance name.
How do I identify an object that is technically not there like the "scrollingBack" and "scrollingForward"?

Comment: I figured out the problem!
I just needed to add "var scrollingBack:Boolean;" and
"var scrollingForward:Boolean;" to get rid of that undefined property error. Thank you for your assistance! It works well now!

Answer (score 0):

I think this may work, have enterframe event listen when the item is rollover and increase the X by every frame unitl the mouse roll out of the button.

```
backScroll_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, backScroll);


function backScroll(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,myButton);
    backScroll_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, backScrollOut);
}

function backScrollOut(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,myButton);
}

function myButton(e:Event):void
{
    timeLine.x+=15;
}
```

Comment: Ninja'd :) But, no check constraints, and multiple addEventListener's to be called for repeated scrolling requests.